# Rewrap generic class

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class GenericClass<T: NSObject> {

    let generic: T
    let somethingElse: String

    init(generic: T, somethingElse: String) {
        self.generic = generic
        self.somethingElse = somethingElse
    }

    func wrap<P: NSObject>(with: P) -> GenericClass<P> {
        return GenericClass(generic: with, somethingElse: somethingElse)
    }
}

class Person {
    func transform() {
        let classA: GenericClass<UIViewController> = GenericClass(generic: UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil), somethingElse: "")
        let rewrapped: GenericClass<UIView> = classA.wrap(with: UIView())
    }
}
```

I get this compiler error:

> Generic parameter 'P' could not be inferred

The compiler can not infer the type, but I don't see why that's necessary in the method. It should just return GenericClass with the specified type.

I want to replace `generic` with another type and keep `somethingElse` intact. Why doesn't it work with the `wrap` method?

Comment: return `GenericClass<P>(...)`. I am not exactly sure why it cannot be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the generic type in `wrap`

```
func wrap<P: NSObject>(with: P) -> GenericClass<P> {
    return GenericClass<P>(generic: with, somethingElse: somethingElse)
}
```